# How do I make my own navigation bar in Umbraco v8

Tags: umbraco7, umbraco8

How do I make my own navigation icons like on Packages, Users, etc. on my custom section "My Custom Section"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have found out this:

Its called navigation and here are the files:

package.manifest

```
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "alias": "testSection",
            "name": "Test Section"
        }
    ],
    "dashboards": [
        {
            "alias": "welcome",
            "sections": [ "testSection" ],
            "view": "~/App_Plugins/TestSection/backoffice/dashboard/sections.html"
        },
    ],
    // array of files we want to inject into the application on app_start
    "javascript": [
        "~/App_Plugins/TestSection/backoffice/dashboard/sections.controller.js"
    ]
}
```

sections.controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function testSectionSections($scope) {

        var tss = this;

        tss.page = {
            title: 'Test Section',
            navigation: [
                {
                    'name': 'Info',
                    'alias': 'info',
                    'icon': 'icon-info',
                    'view': Umbraco.Sys.ServerVariables.umbracoSettings.appPluginsPath + '/TestSection/backoffice/dashboard/info.html',
                    'active': true
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Page2',
                    'alias': 'page2',
                    'icon': 'icon-box',
                    'view': Umbraco.Sys.ServerVariables.umbracoSettings.appPluginsPath + '/TestSection/backoffice/dashboard/page2.html',
                },
            ]
        }

    };

    angular.module('umbraco')
        .controller('testSectionSectionsController', testSectionSections);
})();
```

sections.html

```
<div ng-controller="testSectionSectionsController as tss">

    <umb-editor-view footer="false">
        <umb-editor-header name="tss.page.title"
                           hide-description="true"
                           name-locked="true"
                           hide-alias="true"
                           hide-icon="true"
                           navigation="tss.page.navigation">
        </umb-editor-header>
        <umb-editor-container class="form-horizontal">
            <umb-editor-sub-views sub-views="tss.page.navigation" model="tss"></umb-editor-sub-views>
        </umb-editor-container>
    </umb-editor-view>
</div>
```

info.html

```
<h3>Welcome - Info</h3>
```

**Note:**

When I click "Test Section" I load my custom tree controller on the left and the default dashboard info.html is loaded on the right side and above the dashboard the "section navigation" is properly show on top-right.

The only issue I am having is, when I click an item on my "Tree Controller" on the left, my "section navigation" disappear. I want it to be visible all the time.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can [use Content Apps](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/extending/Content-Apps/) to do that.

Content Apps are a brand new concept in Umbraco 8. They are designed to be companions to the Content Item and they enhance the editor's experience by enabling quick access to contextual information for a particular content item they are editing. Having said that, they are not intended to be used for editing the content.

You follow these steps to create a custom content app, for more details please [check this Umbraco documentation](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Extending/Content-Apps/#creating-a-custom-content-app).

- Setting up a new plugin - [please see details & code samples here](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Extending/Content-Apps/#setting-up-the-plugin).
- Creating a new View and a new Controller for the new plugin - [please see details here.](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Extending/Content-Apps/#creating-the-view-and-the-controller)
- After you are done, you should see your new Content App (for this case, it is the "Word Counter" app).
- Finally; you can set your Content App to be visible only on specific sections by updating your `package.manifest` as [described here.](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Extending/Content-Apps/#limiting-according-to-type)

PS: Here is another article about how to create [Content Apps.](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-8-tutorials/backend-configuration/creating-a-custom-content-tab-within-umbraco-8-content-app-explained/)

PSS: [You can find more examples here](https://umbraco.com/blog/umbraco-8-content-apps/) to inspire you with your custom solution.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have tried Content Apps and it works fine for the content types "Media Types, Member Types, and Document Types in the Settings section"

I cant get it to work with my custom section "My Custom Section"

What I want is, when I click the section "My Custom Section" on the top section, it should show the submenu like i have mentioned in my post and below that:

a tree view to the left(i have got this part to work) and right side, where I want my controller to show depending on what I select on the left side. Kind of Packages and Users sections.